# What is the purpose of C:\Users\%userprofile%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\PRICache and can it be deleted?

Tags: removable

I am trying to make space on my computer and when looking for another folder I came across this. Since it says cache I assume it's safe to remove but want to be sure. All files in it have a.pri extension.
I'm on windows 8.1!

Answer (score 1):

The smart rule is to never delete anything you don't know the purpose of - especially if it's in a 'hidden' folder.

Try using [Disk Cleanup](http://windows.microsoft.com/is-is/windows/delete-files-using-disk-cleanup#delete-files-using-disk-cleanup=windows-8) instead.

Comment: [Better guide here](http://www.howtogeek.com/125923/7-ways-to-free-up-hard-disk-space-on-windows/)

Comment: I know that rule hence why I'm asking the question. And the only way to know the purpose is to ask! Also I did some cleanup utilities but they overall only do very few things.

Comment: My answer was meant to be read as "Leave it alone" rather than as a lesson in how to Google - see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj552947.aspx AppData is hidden precisely to stop people fumbling around in it

Comment: @Tetsujin Oh ok, also many people these days find their way to appdata due to popular games i.e. *Minecraft* being stored there and needing to be accessed to mod or change textures.